# LOAD DATA INFILE - which engine if i have a big file?

Tags: mysql, innodb, myisam

I need an advice from someone who already faced my problem.

I have an over 10 mil. records *.txt file to import into a new table. First, I was looking to find some "expert advices" regarding the best choice for the table Engine.

Unfortunately I've found 50% opinions for InnoDB and 50% opinions for MyISAM. From your experience, keeping in mind the volume of information, and the fact that I will use LOAD DATA INFILE, which is the best choice for my table engine ? 
And please give me some strong arguments :) not just an advice to use one or other !

Second : After I'll decide which engine to choose, let's say MyISAM, if in the future I'll need to use the table in a transaction, I'ts a good practice to  "temporary" change the engine of the table to InnoDB in order to execute the transaction, and after to come back to the first selected choice ?

Answer (score 1):

I think InnoDB is the better option in your case. Take a look into this article: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2008/07/03/how-to-load-large-files-safely-into-innodb-with-load-data-infile/

Answer (score 1):

Innodb loves to be able to have it's indexes in memory, it slows considerably if it can't. MyISAM does much better in low memory situations with large data sets. There are also some unique options available in MyISAM like MERGE tables that will allow you to split large tables into smaller ones and create virtual/merge tables out of the smaller tables.

If you are doing a lot of modifications (insert/update/delete), then Innodb would do better (fewer locking issues). But MyISAM will do just fine if you don't have simultaneous modifications.

Switching table types takes too long, but it is an option. If you want to have both MyISAM and Innodb, setup replication. You can have the table Innodb on one server and MyISAM on the replication server. Tables types don't have to be the same on master/slaves.

Comment: As an aside, I have "logging" tables that are MyISAM that have over 500 million records. If you are only inserting, MyISAM is great.  To speed up your LOAD DATA, you should set your sort buffers really high (regardless of table type). Lower them after import.